# List to numpy array to write with imageio as video

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, video-processing, python-imageio

I have a list as all_frames. I want to write this as a video with imageio but I got the error that you can find in below. How can I change all_frame from list to np.array?

[image: error]

You can find imageio code in below:

```
all_frames = []

 for j, image in enumerate(image_batch): 
        image_index = (i * batch_size) + j
        if not self.use_tf:
            image = (image.permute(1, 2, 0) * 127.5 + 128).clamp(0, 255).to(torch.uint8).squeeze(0)
        array = np.array(image)

        for effect in self.custom_effects:
            array = effect.apply_effect(array = array, 
                                        index = image_index)

        final_image = Image.fromarray(array, 'RGB')

        if resolution:
            final_image = final_image.resize((resolution, resolution))


        
        all_frames.append(final_image)

imageio.mimwrite('tmp.mp4', all_frames, quality=8, fps=self.sr/self.frame_duration)
```

Comment: Due to your code `all_frames` list is empty, but must be a list of 2d arrays.

Comment: There must be some loop that populates `all_frames' with images.

Comment: The problem is in elements that `all_frames` list contains. So post the code related.

Comment: I posted @Hihikomori

Comment: `all_frames` contains PIL images, they are not a numpy arrays. I believe you can add just `array` to `all_frames`

Comment: How, could you please help me? :) @Hihikomori

Comment: Post more code please. There is no understending what is `array` is.

Comment: I made edit @Hihikomori

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this edit:

```
all_frames.append(np.array(final_image,np.uint8))
```

That must converts images to numpy arrays.

Comment: You made it! Thank you!